# How to parse array of struct when creating stream in KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm trying to access a key called session ID, here is what the JSON of my message looks like:

```
{
   "events":[
      {
         "data":{
            "session_id":"-8479590123628083695"}}]}
```

This is my KSQL code to create the stream,

```
CREATE STREAM stream_test(
  
  events ARRAY< data STRUCT< session_id varchar> >
  
) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='my_topic', 
        VALUE_FORMAT='JSON')
```

But I get this error,

```
KSQLError: ("line 4:22: mismatched input 'STRUCT' expecting {'(', 'ARRAY', '>'}", 40001, None)
```

Does anyone know how to unpack this kind of structure? I'm struggling to find examples

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
  events ARRAY< STRUCT<data STRUCT< session_id varchar >> >
```